# How do i remove this data?

Tags: linked-data

[image]

I removed a mesh from my model and the data stayed in the list I can't select it but I can't find a way to delete it.

How do I delete/remove "0 Mast" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 0 means that nothing is assigned to it.

Simply save, exit and open again